# Kiosk mode web application

Tags: javascript, web-applications, kiosk-mode

I am looking for a way to lock down user-screen for my application. The users should essentially not able to move away from the screen until the user completes the steps on the particular page. The focus should be on the page and any other application or system should not be available (unless ctrl+alt+del is pressed). Earlier the browser used to provide way to open window in fullscreen mode through javascript. However now it opens only in sort of extended maximized mode.
Is there a way to lock down the screen? Even if it means creating a browser extension. However, it should be available for different browsers like Internet Explorer, Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Even i faced such problem. The web page is always vulnerable to alt+tab, alt+f4 , ctrl+enter.

Comment: Not natively. There are lots of kiosk software applications that will do this, though. As someone who's put a lot of custom software on tradeshow floors, the best way to do this is to use a third party program.

Comment: Not an ideal solution by looking at your requirements but you could create a simple application with no border & fullscreen and put a WebBrowser control onto it. From there you could handle a lot of the common key combinations (like Al+F4) to do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

[Webconverger](http://webconverger.com/) maintains a Firefox extension that provides a fullscreen view.

[image: Kiosk in fullscreen]

[Source](https://github.com/Webconverger/iceweasel-webconverger/tree/master/src)

I recommend using the Webconverger OS and having a `chrome=webcfullscreen` configuration to ease deployment though.